# What is the best way to turn IPython Notebooks on Github to a blog?

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I've some IPython notebooks which I maintain at GitHub. I would like to turn them into a blog. I would like to have a discussion area at the end of the notebooks so that readers can comment. I do not want users to be able to execute the codes directly on the site (it is enough if they can see the notebooks), if they want to execute, they can copy the codes and run on their own computers. If possible I do not want a separate copy of the notebooks, I would like to have a single copy for ease of maintenance. What is the best way (preferably a free way) to achieve this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hamel Husain recently posted to the Jupyter discourse forum [a very full-featured Jupyter blogging system hosted on GitHub Pages](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/a-new-open-source-jupyter-blogging-system-hosted-on-github-pages/3334?u=fomightez) called [fastpages](https://github.com/fastai/fastpages). It seems well documented and state-of-the-art. It allows a comments section, see [here](https://github.com/fastai/fastpages#enabling-comments).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to export a static version of the notebooks? You can use a tool like `nbconvert` which according to [its documentation](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> allows you to convert a Jupyter .ipynb notebook document file into another static format including HTML, LaTeX, PDF, Markdown, reStructuredText, and more. nbconvert can also add productivity to your workflow when used to execute notebooks programmatically.

You can export in your desired format and add the remaining markup for commenting or other functionality.